# Get a path to a different plugin

Tags: plugin-development, directory

To get a the path to a plugin you can use `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)` - but this obviously has to be called from within the plug-in.

How can you *reliably* get the path to plugin B (`pluginb/pluginb.php`) from within plug-in A?

**Edit:** Its assumed you know the slug of the plug-in you're after (actually you can get them from `get_plugins()`). But I would like it to work generally.

Comment: Would this apply to any plugin? or one/several in particular? If the latter, are they your own, or public releases?

Comment: So I'm assuming you know the slug of the plug-in you're after: e.g `pluginb/pluginb.php`, but its third-party.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My best guess would be:

```
if ( ! is_file( $dir = WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR . '/pluginb/pluginb.php' ) ) {
    if ( ! is_file( $dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/pluginb/pluginb.php' ) )
        $dir = null;
}

return $dir;
```

However, the danger here is still the assumption of the plugin's "basename" - a well written plugin will still function even when its directory and/or main file has been renamed (for whatever reason).

Which goes back to my original comment - depending on *which* third-party plugin this is referring to, many authors define their own methods/constants to hold the plugin path - it would make sense to check for their existence & use these instead (if available).

Comment: Ah ok, I've updated the question :). You can get the plug-ins slug from `get_plugins()` - in my use case there is enough. If you are after some specific plug-in, and nothing better is available, I guess you can search for the plug-in via name in `get_plugins()`.

Comment: +1 Would ideally like to avoid using constants - but this solution at least checks when using them :) - and is how core seems to do things.

Answer (score 2):

So one method is to call [`plugin_dir_path()`](http://queryposts.com/function/plugin_dir_path/) within the current plug-in and replace your own plugin directory name with that of the slug of the plug-in you're after (`pluginb/pluginb.php`):

So within our plug-in `plugina/plugina.php`,

```
$plugin_b = str_replace('plugina/','pluginb/pluginb.php',plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
echo $plugin_b; //Prints path/to/pluginb/pluginb.php';
```

Comment: I would advise against this, since there is the assumption that plugin B is in the same directory as A (which won't neccessarily be the case, ala MU plugins).

Comment: Thanks, thought there would be something that I'd miss :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` constant in your pluginA, for example:

```
include_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/pluginb/pluginb.php');
```

Extra info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories